# Error using non-constant real valued expression for synthesizable VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

```
 when f9 =>
       if melcol < 128 and framcounter < 2560 then
           temp <= std_logic_vector(signed(framout)*to_signed(melf(melrow,melcol),8));
           firstmelout <= firstmelout + (to_integer(unsigned(temp)))/1000;
           melcol <= melcol+1;
           framcounter <= framcounter+1;
           fstate <= f9;
       elsif melcol = 128 and melrow < 13 and framcounter < 2560 then
           -----MEMORY NEEDED
           framcounter <= framcounter -128;
           melrow <= melrow+1;      --melrow filter number
           melcol <= 0;
           secondmelout <= firstmelout;
           fstate <= f10;
       elsif melcol = 128 and melrow = 13 and framcounter < 2560 then
           ---------MEMORY NEEDED
           framcounter <= framcounter +128;
           melrow <= 0;
           melcol <= 0;
           secondmelout <= firstmelout;
           fstate <= f10;
       elsif framcounter = 2560 then
           flagmel <= '1';
           fstate <= f12;
       else fstate <= f12;
       end if;

   when f10 =>
       varmel <= real(secondmelout);
       --varmel := LOG10(firstmelout);
       --varlogresult := 100*varlogresult;
       wea3(0) <= '1';
       --logresult <= intlogresult;
       fstate <= f11;
```

I have a problem to convert non-constant integer to real. I want to take log10 of the firstmelout, but real type is needed. So I tried to cast it to real by using "real()" but Vivado returns this error message;
non-constant real valued expression is not supported

I tried lots of things but i couldn't solve it, I'm waiting your helps guys
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you need to read these... http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Float_ug.pdf and http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Fixed_ug.pdf

Comment: [IMPORTANT:  You cannot define a synthesizable object of type real](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf#143)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, instead of using `real` type for synthesis applications, you should define your logic in terms of fixed or floating point types, which are synthesizable. You may find that in the process of changing your logic to use these new types that you will need to rethink how to implement what you are trying to achieve.

As stated by others in comments, check out these resources:

- User guide for [fixed](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Fixed_ug.pdf) and [floating](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/Float_ug.pdf) point types
- Manual/user guide for the synthesis tool that you are using. For example, [Vivado Synthesis User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_4/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf).